# How to set the Intellisense on javascript to expose the properties of the parameter

Tags: single-page-application, javascript-intellisense

I downloaded your SPA sample from the GitHub. My question is about the Intellisense on javascript. I notice, if type  "toastr." in sessionadd.js then I the Intellisense gives the accurate list of options, but if I type "datacontext.", the Intellisense can't give the accurate list of options.
I would expect that the Intellisense still worked correctly in this case. Is there a way to set the Intellisense to give the accurate list in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Visual Studio. It has an awful default intellisence and refractoring for JavaScript. But in his videos, John Papa uses [JetBrains' ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which provides excellent additional tools for various things in Visual Studio, including JavaScript intellisence. However, it is not free.